# Get fixture and component values on describe call - Angular unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit tests for web application which contains too many forms. So, for code optimization I am creating **one common function which will return function**. That function tests all the supplied form fields(ReactiveFroms approach) whether they are required or not.

Function that tests whether fields are required or not.

**common-function.spec.ts:**

```
export const componentTestFn = (formGroup: any, fields: Fields[], configurationOptions?) => () => {

describe('On required fields', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {

        if (configurationOptions) {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule(configurationOptions)
                .compileComponents();
        }

    });


    fields.forEach(element => {

        describe(element.name, () => {
            it('should be a required field', () => {

                let control = formGroup.get(element.formControlName);
                if (element.nestedControl) {
                    control = control.get(element.nestedControl);
                }
                control.patchValue('');
                expect(control.hasError('required')).toBeTruthy();
                control.patchValue('Test');
                expect(control.hasError('required')).toBeFalsy();
            });
        });

    });

});

}
```

And I am calling this function from main spec file with describe clause.

**main.component.spec.ts:**

```
describe('Given a Physical Property Setup Component', () => {

     let component: PhysicalPropertySetupComponent;
     let fixture: ComponentFixture<PhysicalPropertySetupComponent>;
     let fields: Fields[] = [
           new Fields('','field1','',''),
           new Fields('','field2','',''),
           new Fields('','field3','',''),
           new Fields('','field4','','')
     ];

     beforeEach(() => {
           TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                 ....
           });
           fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PhysicalPropertySetupComponent);
           component = fixture.componentInstance;
     });
     describe('Testing',common.componentTestFn(component.formGroup,fields));
});
```

**But it is giving me error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'formGroup' of undefined".**

I think it is because we can only use component and fixture value inside `it` clause. But i'm not using it because my `componentTestFn` will replace it. Similarly when i call this function inside `it` it works fine.

Can anybody tell me how can i get that `formGroup` value on describe? Any Help will be appreciated.

**Thanks in advance!!**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting it into the describe function, make a function that will create a describe :

```
export const componentTestFn = (
  formGroup: any, 
  fields: Fields[], 
  configurationOptions?, 
  componentTested?
) => () => {...});
```

And call it like that :

```
componentTestFn(common.componentTestFn(component.formGroup, fields, undefined, 'Testing'));
```

Comment: Thanks @trichetriche, I tried that too!!.. But was getting same error!

Comment: In this case you will need to make only expectations in your function, and call it inside `it`s, I don't see another way ...